# How to get full path to the texture of the material?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have material, I want to change the texture (mainTexture) on a fragment of a texture atlas. But in order to know which to use the atlas I need to get the full path to the current texture.
How to get a guid "texture asset" or just the full path to the texture of the material?
News for Editor, but not for the Runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you would need someinfo of the texture to get the path

[AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath.html)

[To get/load all the textures, you must use the Resources class; Syntax is below:](http://Resources.LoadAll(string%20resourceRelativePath,%20type%20fileType)%20:%20Object[])